# How to change string[] in code to stringbuilder?

Tags: c#

I made a code that merge text files. But it works too slow and I want to change string to stringbuilder. But it doesn't worked well. How to change string to stringbuilder?

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Text1 = new[] { this.textBox1.Text };
        string[] Text2 = new[] { this.textBox2.Text };

        string[] Word1 = this.textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] Word2 = this.textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);


        //            this.textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (Word1.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < Word1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Join("", Word1[i])))
                {
                    this.textBox3.Text = this.textBox3.Text + Word1[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textBox3.Text = this.textBox3.Text + Word2[j];
                    j = j + 1;
                }
                this.textBox3.Text = this.textBox3.Text + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "But it doesn't worked well" - What did not work well? what did you try with StringBuilder?

Comment: Do you want to convert string[] to stringbuilder??

Comment: this: `string[] Text1 = new[] { this.textBox1.Text };` makes no sense, why make an array if you're going to fill it with 1 item -_-

Comment: I'd suggest checking your code first: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Join("", Word1[i])` is always true. You're also updating the text in a textbox on every pass in the `for...next` loop - this text you need to create using a `stringbuilder` and set it after the `for..next` loop.

Comment: You should consider to bring the working code (including the changes from answer here) to CodeReview along with an explanation what exactly you try to achieve. There is a bulk of unnecessary, complex and unsafe code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not the use of string but that you work in a usercontrol. This should be a lot faster:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Text1 = new[] { this.textBox1.Text };
    string[] Text2 = new[] { this.textBox2.Text };

    string[] Word1 = this.textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] Word2 = this.textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);


    //            this.textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    string outStr = string.Empty;

    if (Word1.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < Word1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Join("", Word1[i])))
            {
                outStr = outStr + Word1[i];
            }
            else
            {
                outStr = outStr + Word2[j];
                j = j + 1;
            }
            outStr = outStr + "\r\n";
        }

        this.textBox3.Text = outStr;
    }
}
```

**StringBuilder**

This is the solution with a `StringBuilder`:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Text1 = new[] { this.textBox1.Text };
    string[] Text2 = new[] { this.textBox2.Text };

    string[] Word1 = this.textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] Word2 = this.textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);


    //            this.textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder();

    if (Word1.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < Word1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Join("", Word1[i])))
            {
                outStr.Append(Word1[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                outStr.Append(Word2[j]);
                j = j + 1;
            }
            outStr.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        this.textBox3.Text = outStr.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat. It is so FAST. Thanks!